# Preserve navigation properties on detached entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

After detaching an entity, all of its navigation properties are nulled out:

```
var useraccount = ctx.UserAccounts
                     .Include("User")
                     .SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserAccountId == 15);

if(useraccount.User != null)
      Console.WriteLine("User is not null!");

ctx.Entry(useraccount).State = System.Data.EntityState.Detached;

if(useraccount.User== null)
      Console.WriteLine("User is now null!");
```

What's the easiest way to preserve that navigation property>?

Answer (score 0):

is create one instance of your ENTITY before you detached

var conserver=useraccount;
ctx.Entry(useraccount).State = System.Data.EntityState.Detached;

Comment: Still null, as `conserver` and `useraccount` reference the same object.

Comment: so, in the seccion when you get the var useraccount, make this twice with diferents var name, one for useraccount and other with the useraccount2,if this not help you, other may can be after your get the value in useraccount, create manually the ENTITY USERACCOUNT asigning all property values of entity..